# ERROR: Unable to locate a modulefile for 'gcc/9.4.0'

Tags: linux, gcc, environment-modules

ERROR: Unable to locate a modulefile for 'gcc/9.4.0'

Hi everyone.
I don't have much experience on linux, and I have some problems on loading a module.
I use a command like: module load gcc/9.4.0
but get a result like: ERROR: Unable to locate a modulefile for 'gcc/9.4.0'

What should I do next?
And if I successfully load the module, can I use the command like: icc -o xxxxx?
I will be appriciated if you can recommendate some books for beginners!

Thank you!

Comment: What does the command `module avail` show?

Comment: Welcome to the community!  When typing code, error messages, etc. into your questions, you can put backticks (``) around such text to display them better.

Answer (score -1):

follow the steps below to set up the environment variable for linux

first type `module --version` if not showing anything, install it first
check to see the correct modulepath and modulefiles. use `echo $MODULEPATH` to see the directories containing modulefiles.
you will see directories where the module command will look for modulefiles
type `modinfo -n gcc/9.4.0` to see the full path to the module file and if it's not there, then you need to create one in your home directory
or another modulepath.

to load the module for gcc/9.4.0 use `module load gcc/9.4.0`. this should set the environment variables and paths for using
gcc-9 as your compiler.
and yes, you can use the `icc -0 xxxxx` to compile your code with gcc-9

for a deep understanding the following link will help:

> https://modules.readthedocs.io/en/latest/INSTALL.html
> https://southgreenplatform.github.io/trainings/hpc/moduleinstallation/

```
> book: linux pocket guide by daniel J. Barrett 
> 
> book: The linux command line by william shotts
```